# How to use | translate to ng-treetable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to do localization In ng-treetable
In my below code

```
<ay-treeTable [value]="temp">
            <ay-column field="item_no" header="ITEM_NO" | translate></ay-column>
</ay-treeTable>
```

I am getting this error

ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '|' is not a valid attribute name.

So how to use "| translate" for header

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-treetable

Comment: you can try this `header="ITEM_NO | translate"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
header="{{'ITEM_NO' | translate}}"
```